# Weird Div Padding

Tags: css, html, padding

I am new to CSS so please don't be to harsh on me. I am trying to place the yellow background DIV right below the "Header" DIV, but for some reason, it seems to place a padding before and after and I don't really understand why. If I remove the list, than the problem disappears.

This is the HTML code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="headerDiv">
    <p>Header</p>
</div>
<div id="listDiv">
    <ul>
<li>Menu item 1</li> 
      <li>Menu item 1</li> 
      <li>Menu item 1</li> 
      <li>Menu item 1</li> 
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="mainviewDiv">
Main View
</div>
<div id="footerDiv">
Footer
</div>

</body>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

div#headerDiv { background-color:#F00;
         height:100px;
         position:relative;
         }

div#listDiv {background-color:#FF0;
        }

div#listDiv ul {list-style-type:none;}

div#listDiv li { display:inline;}

div#mainviewDiv {background-color:#060;}

div#footerDiv {background-color:#999;}
```

[image]

Comment: http://www.cssreset.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you have tried this, but adding this to the top of your CSS file might help you out:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

But when you publish your website use [Eric Myers CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

And like Maxime Morin said, you might want to check out http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

Answer (score 3):

set your `#listDiv` and `#headerDiv` to have a `margin:0px;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the top margin of the `ul` element, due to [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Also make sure the divs don't have a margin and padding (which they probably have not, because divs don't have margins by default.

People often use [CSS reset like this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove all those margins and paddings on all elements. After that, you can add specific styling where you need it. You should consider using that once you start the 'real' styling.

Answer (score 1):

Renders fine in Chrome telling me you're probably using IE. You can solve issues like this by using a CSS reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ which sets all your CSS elements back to 0 so all browsers start at the same point, overriding some of their built in default CSS.

The thing to keep in mind about resets is you know have to style each element you use. For example lists will have no padding, no default list style etc. You can of course remove some items from the reset but that sort of defeats the purpose of them.

Comment: [Normalize.css](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/) is an other option for CSS reset.

Comment: Normalize is actually probably better for most newcomers, very good point!

Answer (score 0):

Some tags has default styles - even if you don't really declare them.
You can override this rules for example by adding simple:

```
margin:0; 
padding:0;
```

into your CSS declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Your Unordered list is creating left padding of 40. Replace your code with this:

```
div#listDiv ul {list-style-type:none;
 padding:0;
 }
```

You will come across a lot of default styles troubles if you're just starting out. Keep at it and you will learn. We all had to start somewhere!

Comment: make sure to add margin:0, that might also be causing a problem.